# Trying to work with axis 1 in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that calculates the least regret of an array. I have managed to work out how to find the minimum value for a column and then work out what the difference between the minimum is and the original values. However, as I am a novice I cannot do the same for rows. I am working with the following script:

```
#find the minimum values for rows and columns:
col_min=np.min(array)
col_min0=array.min(0)
row_min=np.min(array[:,2])
row_min0=array.min(1)

#difference or least regret for col:
least_reg_col=0
for i in array:
    least_reg_col=col_min0-i
    print(least_reg_col)

#difference or least regret for row:
least_reg_row=0
for j in np.array(array,axis=1):
    least_reg_row=array-j
    print(least_reg_row)
```

For the matrix:
       s1  s2  s3
    0   1   5   2
    1   3   4   0
    2   2   2   4
    3   5   1   0

My columns turn out like so:

```
[ 0 -4 -2]
[-2 -3  0]
[-1 -1 -4]
[-4  0  0]
```

But I cannot work through the rows due to be a novice; which should be:

```
[ 0 -4 -1]
[-3 -4  0]
[ 0  0 -2]
[-5 -1  0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope useful to you

```
a = np.array([[0,1,5],
              [2,1,3],
              [4,0,2],
              [2,2,4]])

r = np.min(a,axis=0)
c = np.min(a,axis=1)
ridx = np.argmin(a,axis=0)
cidx = np.argmin(a,axis=1)
rdif = a-r
cdif = a-c[:,None]

print (rdiff)
print (cdiff)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help Weidong, that script works a treat.